# git rebase to create new branch and leave original where it is

Tags: git

I have a situation in which I have to maintain two branches over an extended period of time, and 'merge' is not attractive, since only selective changes should be carried back and forth. So I've learned to use cherry-pick. However, another alternative occured to me, but I fear that the rebase command lacks the necessary option.

git rebase makes a set of new commits and then move a branch label to point to the last one. What I think I want here is simple: I want to leave the old branch label alone, and create a brand new branch label. My hypothesized workflow is to use this mechanism to create a single, squashed, commit, for cherry-picking, without rewriting history as seen by others.

An approximation that occurred to me was to make a clone, rebase -i in the clone, rename the branch, and push the results back. Is there a way to do this directly with git rebase that I'm missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are on the branch you want to keep, you can just create a new branch from current HEAD

```
git fetch
git branch backup_of_feature_ABZ
git rebase -i origin/master # if you are rebasing onto master
# then you can just squash or pick the change you want and you keep your "backup branch"
# Which makes good sense since it is backup and you did deliver the squashed commit.
```

I hope i understood your problem correctly

Comment: D'oh! There's something paradigmatic that I was missing,and now you've repaired me.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want to create a single squashed commit for multiple commits then you can still use `cherry-pick`.

The following command chain would squash the last three commits of the given branch:

```
git cherry-pick -n <branch>...<branch>~3
git commit -m "Squash 3 commits from <branch>"
```

`git cherry-pick -n` stands for `--no-commit` ([documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)) which applys all changes to your working tree while not doing a commit (obviously).

You could easily create an alias for this using a shell function.

Hope that helps.